# Is there a way to delay a Mail by seconds or minutes when sending in laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried using later and queue then specified the seconds like below but i get an error saying "**Only mailables may be queued**"

```
Mail::later(5, $email)->send(new PasswordMail($data));
```

and

```
Mail::later(5, $email)->queue(new PasswordMail($data));
```

Here is my code when sending the email

```
Mail::to($email)->send(new PasswordMail($data));
```

Comment: what about [`sleep`](https://php.net/sleep)?

Comment: Wont using sleep mean the browser will sleep for the specified amount of time before sending the email? Let me try sleep

Comment: "sleep — Delay execution" in the server level, which is means that the browser will hang on until the response is received, which means yes. if you mean queueing the mail sending so sleep will not the thing you want to use

Comment: Yes i mean queueing the mail. Later and Queue are both not working eveb using the laravel docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#queueing-mail) clearly describe how to delay mail sending:

> ###### Delayed Message Queueing
>
> If you wish to delay the delivery of a queued email message, you may use the `later` method. As its first argument, the `later` method accepts a `DateTime` instance indicating when the message should be sent:
>
> ```
> $when = now()->addMinutes(10);
>
> Mail::to($request->user())
>     ->cc($moreUsers)
>     ->bcc($evenMoreUsers)
>     ->later($when, new OrderShipped($order));
> ```

So in your case:

```
Mail::to($email)->later(now()->addMinutes(5), new PasswordMail($data));
```